# Perl write to a file not working with cron job

Tags: perl, curl, cron

So, I have a fairly large script in perl, and I just recently began to utilize Cron from my server hosts.

Within the script, I write to a file like this:

```
$filename = 'ids.txt';
open($fh, '>>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh "$id ";
close $fh;
print "Write to File Complete.\n";
```

When I execute the CGI script normally (by visiting the page from my browser) it works completely fine.
Though, when I use Cron to execute the script automatically, apparently nothing ever gets written to the file.

Within the same script,  I also write cookies (with cURL) to a file like this:

```
my $CURL = "curl -s -b cookie_$id -c cookie_$id -L";
```

Then of course execute it using tic marks (`). Which normally does work. Supposed to write the cookie to the file name cookie_(whatever the variable ID is).

Though when using Cron, somehow it bypasses this.

In order for the script to accomplish its task IT MUST write the cookie to a file. Which it never does. Though seemingly does accomplish the task anyways (though doesn't write to ids.txt).

I use Godaddy as Server Hosts.

Currently using Linux CPanel hosting.

*** Note: I have not put in any special parameters to make the script 'cron' friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that scripts running out of cron have different environment variables. The PATH variable, in particular, is something to watch.

If you run the above script out of cron, "id.txt" will go to the working directory that cron executed your script in, which also may not be what you expect.

The best thing to do is fully qualify your path names (e.g. /tmp/id.txt instead of id.txt) and set up logging to one of these fully qualified path names so you can catch these errors.

Comment: When I set up my crons in a mixed environment I too set the paths right in the cron tab.